# Listen for any kind of event

Tags: air, flex4

I'm developping an application in which I need to set up a timeout.
But I have to watch for a total inactivity.
Is there anyway I could watch for any kind of event ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that would cover all kinds of user events, you'd have to listen for each of the various key, mouse events you're interested in but of course you can use a single handler for them all.

Anyways it sounds like you're looking for something like [SystemManger's idle event](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/SystemManager.html#event:idle).  However that is locked to a 1sec threshold.

If you still need to roll your own you can listen to systemManager which is accessible in mx.core.Application or any UIComponent for that matter.

You could also listen to the stage but SystemManager is the recommended app-wide event source in a flex app.